# Insertar datos de un DataTable a una tabla de SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

necesito ayuda en como INSERTAR datos de un DataTable a una tabla de SQL el código de mi DataTable es el siguiente:

```
public DataTable dtDetalle = new DataTable("Detalle");

public DataTable filldata()
{
    dtDetalle.Columns.Add("idProducto", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dtDetalle.Columns.Add("Producto", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dtDetalle.Columns.Add("Cantidad", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    dtDetalle.Columns.Add("Precio", Type.GetType("System.Single"));
    dtDetalle.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.Single"));
    return dtDetalle;
}
```

Con esto agrego registros al DataTable

```
try
    {
        if (Session["dt"] == null)
        {
            DataTable dt = filldata();
            DataRow Row1;
            Row1 = dt.NewRow();
            Row1["idProducto"] = txtProducto.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Row1["Producto"] = txtProducto.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            Row1["Cantidad"] = txtCantidad.Text;
            Row1["Precio"] = txtTotal.Text;
            Row1["Total"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(Row1);
            datalistadoDetalle.DataSource = dt;
            datalistadoDetalle.DataBind();
            Session["dt"] = dt;
            dtDetalle = dt;
            limpiarDetalle();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = (Session["dt"]) as DataTable;
            DataRow Row1;
            Row1 = dt.NewRow();
            Row1["idProducto"] = txtProducto.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Row1["Producto"] = txtProducto.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            Row1["Cantidad"] = txtCantidad.Text;
            Row1["Precio"] = txtTotal.Text;
            Row1["Total"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(Row1);
            datalistadoDetalle.DataSource = dt;
            datalistadoDetalle.DataBind();
            Session["dt"] = dt;
            dtDetalle = dt;
            limpiarDetalle();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate, estuve buscando información y encontre esto: [Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008 (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.90).aspx) esta ingles por eso tratare de hacer un resumen de lo que aqui aparece debido al idioma.

lo primero que debes tener es una tabla en tu BD SQL donde vas a guardar los valores con los mismos campos de tu data table luego creas un  store procedure (procedimiento almacenado en español) de la siguiente forma:

Si tu tabla se llama `dbo.CategoryTabletype`

crea el store procedure con uno de los parametros como el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateCategories 
    (@tvpNewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY)
```

y luego para insertar debes usar algo como esto en tu sp

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)
    SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate este ejemplo, lo puedes adaptar a tus necesidades:

```
public void ObtenerValores(DataTable dt)
{
   foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
      string a =r[0].ToString();
      string b=r[1].ToString();
      Insertar("INSERT INTO  NOBRE_TABLA (NOMBRE_CAMPO_a , NOMBRE_CAMPO_b) VALUES (@par1,@par2)",a,b);
     }
}

 public Boolean Insertar(String SQL, String par1, String par2)
        {
            Boolean r = false;
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(SQL, TuCadenaDeConexion);

            try
            {
                comando.Connection.Open();
                comando.Parameters.Clear();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", par1);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", par2);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comando.Connection.Close();
                r = true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex) { comando.Connection.Close(); }

            return r;
        }
```

Comment: Es algo problematico insertar codigo aqui ..aveces no agarra el formato correcto y aparece como texto..por eso pego la imagen

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC edita y en caso requieras ayuda para darle formato, toda la comunidad os apoya :D

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [database_name]
GO
procedimiento almacenado

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateAccount]
    @firstName varchar(200) = NULL,
    @lastName varchar(200) = NULL,
    @email  varchar(200) = NULL,
    @password varchar(200) = NULL,
    @zip varchar(200) = NULL,
    @userStatus  varchar(200) = NULL,
    @createDate datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (FirstName,LastName,Email,Password,Zip,UserStatus, CreateDate) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@email,@password,@zip,@userStatus,@createDate);
END
////////////////////////////////////

 MetodoDB.Sp_CreateAccount("sp_CreateAccount", "UNKNOW", "UNKNOW", txtMail2.Text.Trim().ToLower (), Sub.EncriptatePass(txtPassword2.Text.Trim()), "0000", "0", DateTime.Now);
//////////////////////////////////////////
     public Object Sp_CreateAccount(String sP, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String zip, String userStatus, DateTime createDate)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sP, Conexion1);
            Object Objeto = new Object();
            try
            {
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comando.Connection.Open();
                comando.Parameters.Clear();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip",zip);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userStatus", userStatus);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createDate", createDate);
                Objeto = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comando.Connection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex) { comando.Connection.Close(); Error = ex.ToString(); }

            return Objeto;
        }
```

Comment: Algo que como una exicación de lo que el código hace? Para ser una mejor respuesta...